# Google calendar, sharing, user identification

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid, google-calendar-api

I am working on simple application which creates google calendar (under it's own account). I want to share this calendar to other users, but I don't know how to identify them (scope user). I have authenticated them with google openid, so I have their openid identifier, but calendar sharing requires some google id, which I don't have. Where/how can I obtain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found and easy - when authenticating user with oauth, there is possibility to get users e-amil. This is exactly the email address of the account, which was used for authentication = exactly what we need.

Comment: Please make the contents of the comment the text of this answer (and delete the comment if you wish) - the answer should contain the actual answer, not a reference to it.

Comment: @NickJohnson thanks for your advice! I changed the post as proposed.